VS 2022 in Admin not getting Sign-in
I've been trying to sign-in VS 2022 Professional edition, here is a screenshot below.

Now I've used the normal mode to sign-in it works but as I try to use Admin mode it keeps on rotating it. I've removed VS 2022 lots of times but still this issue persists.
The version is 17.11.1.

It is asking for a MS account sign-in: not a local user sign-in.  You can sign in to the MS account as any local user - admin or non admin

@cup it is a MS account sign-in starting the app with admin shows above pop up, but for normal mode it works nice with that MS account sign-in.

So how did you install VS?  Did you install it as admin or non-admin?  Where is it installed - in Program Files or in your roaming profile.  Just asking because it works for me.

If you still can't log in properly, you may want to try this method: Navigate to %localappdata%, and delete .IdentityService this folder. This approach is effective in most cases.
